# Adding accessibility tabbing to html5 video tag

Tags: html, video, accessibility

I've created a video page with HTML5 video and added a tabindex to the video tag. However, it is not possible to tab into the controls, any idea why this could be?

This is the first line of the video block:

```
                                                <video tabindex="0" class="video-js" width="640" height="264" controls="controls" poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to be very browser dependent: it's really up to the browser as to what type of controls it displays. In IE and Firefox, the whole video element gets focus; space toggles play/pause, left/right moves current position, up/down adjust volume. Firefox only displays controls while mouse is over the element (accessibility bug!). (Chrome will let it take focus if you have tabindex="0", but doesn't let you do anything useful via keyboard, so it appears to be effectively keyboard inaccessible.)

If you really want consistent accessibility and UI experience across different browsers, you could create your own controls using HTML+CSS+JavaScript.

Comment: OK, thanks for that. It looks like creating custom controls will be the way forward. Thanks.